# Auto-layout breaks when .col has a .table-responsive child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When using Bootstrap's [auto-layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width) grid one can explicitly specify width of just some of the columns, while rest of the columns split remaining space evenly. However, if one of the auto-`.col`s has a `.table-responsive` child the whole system seems to break down:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="height:40px;border: thick solid red">
      Row 1: auto-layout .col works fine
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3" style="height:40px;border: thick solid green">
      .col .col-3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="height:120px;border: thick solid red">
      Row 2: auto-layout .col > .table-responsive = broken grid
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3" style="height:120px;border: thick solid green">
      .col .col-3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I place a `.table-responsive` child within Bootstrap's grid **wihout specifying explicit width**, so that it behaves consistently? Or in other words, how to make both rows look the same in the example - without vertical break after the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` on your `table-responsive` `parent` div

```
<div class="col" style="height:120px;border: thick solid red; overflow-x:auto">
      Row 2: auto-layout .col > .table-responsive = broken grid
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="height:40px;border: thick solid red">
      Row 1: auto-layout .col works fine
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3" style="height:40px;border: thick solid green">
      .col .col-3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="height:120px;border: thick solid red; overflow:auto">
      Row 2: auto-layout .col > .table-responsive = broken grid
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
              <th style="min-width:400px">foobarbazbarfoo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3" style="height:120px;border: thick solid green">
      .col .col-3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```